# Ipomoea / Morning Glory leaves "engraved" with whitish, silvery patches

Tags: watering, leaves, sunlight, morning-glory, weather

I hope you can help me identify the problem with these Ipomoeas (Morning Glory).

It's actually two varieties of seeds I sowed together:

- Ipomoea Violacea (those with tinnier leaves, I'm not sure)
- Ipomoea Tricolor Heavenly Blue (those with larger, rounder leaves, I'm not sure).

**As you can see from the pictures, some whitish, silvery patches are appearing on leaves.**

I've already looked at the following similar questions...

- [What is happening to the leaves of my Ipomoea (Morning glory)?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7063/what-is-happening-to-the-leaves-of-my-ipomoea-morning-glory)
- [What is causing yellow leaves on my Morning Glory?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/19402/what-is-causing-yellow-leaves-on-my-morning-glory)

...but I am not sure it's the same problem because in those questions it seems that the leaves became just decolored, while on mines it seems more that some of **the leaf *tissue*  came off, and the lower layer of it became exposed** (the patches).

Relevant facts:

- I sawed the seeds approximately one month ago.
- Plants have been taking 5-6 hours of direct sunlight and 4 hours of indirect sunlight a day.
- When plants' height was half of what it is now, there was an hailstorm, resulting in very few leaves being clearly broken/cut, but this seems to not have to do with the whitish patches, because they also started appearing on intact, unbroken leaves. However - I am not sure if this is important - when the hailstorm happened, the hail on the ground did not unfreeze immediately (it was at night).
- There is no trace of insects on the top face or bottom face of the leaves.
- Concerning watering, I've watered them every time I saw the ground become dry, so for the first two weeks, approximately once every 3-4 days. Then two weeks ago it got warmer, so I've started watering them more (once every 2 days). Then last week got even warmer so since then I've started watering them almost daily. These days maximum daytime temperature is 22° Celsius. At night it gets to 8-10° Celsius.
- The patches appeared initially only on some plants, and now more of them are showing the same thing, although not all of them.
- It seems leaves are still growing, although slowly, and new leaflets are coming out.
- I used a universal soil and did not add anything to it.

Sorry if I made this question too long, but I tried to be as much detailed as I could. Please let me know if there is something I might have forgotten to include.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started watering even more and it fixed it :)

[image]